# The argument type '' can't be assigned to the parameter type ''

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I want to implement a search button in my code that searches through Firebase Realtime Database and displays it. Currently, I have a listview that shows all the destinations and a search function to return the search results.

Displaying all items in list:

```
children: <Widget>[
   exampleList.length == 0
   ? Center(
      child: Text(
         "Loading...")
   : ListView.builder(
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      shrinkWrap: true,
      physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      itemCount: exampleList.length,
      itemBuilder: (_, index) {
         return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 5, 0, 5),
            child: UICard(
               title: exampleList[index].name,
               onTap: () {},
               img: 'assets/icons/temp.png'),
            );
         })
     ]
```

Appbar where searchMethod has been implmented:

```
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          elevation: 0,
          leading: Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
                color: Colors.black,
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                });
          }),
          title: !searchState
              ? Text('Store Items',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                      color: Colors.black))
              : TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Search..'),
                  onChanged: (input) {
                    searchMethod(input);
                  },
                ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            !searchState
                ? IconButton(
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.search),
                    color: Colors.black,
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        searchState = !searchState;
                      });
                    },
                  )
                : IconButton(
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.cancel),
                    color: Colors.black,
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        searchState = !searchState;
                      });
                    },
                  )
          ],
        ),
```

searchMethod function:

```
  void searchMethod(String input) {
    DatabaseReference searchRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance
        .reference()
        .child('Database')
        .child('Store');

    searchRef.once().then((DataSnapshot snapShot) {
      exampleList.clear();
      var keys = snapShot.value.keys;
      var values = snapShot.value;

      for (var key in keys) {
        UICard results = new UICard(
          title: values[key]['name'],
          img: values[key]['name'],
          onTap: () {},
        );
        if (results.title.contains(input)) {
          exampleList.add(results);
        }
      }
      Timer(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
        setState(() {});
      });
    });
  }
```

In `exampleList.add(results)` line, I am getting `The argument type 'UICard' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'StoreItem'.`

The StoreItem class is :

```
class StoreItem {
  String name;
  String description;
  String category;

  StoreItem(this.name, this.description, this.category);
}
```

Can I know where I went wrong? How do I fix this?

Comment: You are trying to add different type of data into a different type of list. You cannot add results (which is of type UICard) into exampleList (which is of type StoreItem). You can only add the same kind of types in the same kind of `List`.

Comment: I see where I went wrong. I fixed it by making results into type of StoreItem, thank you so much!